# MVC4 Site Options

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Where or how exactly do you pass configuration settings (stored in a database) to your views?

Let's say a user can set different settings in his profile. These options should be available in every view and partial view.

Some options:

- Global static variables - Bad practice
- Viewbag?
- Wrapper class that contains the 'actual' model and a 'configuration' model.

And where would you put the logic to obtain the information?
I'd like to avoid calling a method in each and every action (using a custom base controller maybe?)

I've tried searching 'mvc options', 'global variables mvc', 'viewbag mvc', 'configuration mvc', ... Nothing relevant came up. I'm probably just using the wrong search keywords.

Thanks!

Comment: You might find the singleton pattern interesting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - Global static variables - Bad practice

Not only it's bad practice but they are shared among all users. In your case you need per-user information

> - Viewbag?

Weakly typed collection relying on magic strings, bad practice. I don't like it nor would ever use it.

> - Wrapper class that contains the 'actual' model and a 'configuration' model.

Yes, you could use a common base view model for all your views that will contain the Settings property.

> And where would you put the logic to obtain the information?

One possibility would be to have a global action filter that will execute **after** each action, retrieve the model passed to the view and since all your models will derive from a common base view model, query the database and assign a value to the settings property.

There's also another approach you might consider. You mentioned that you need this information in every view. Instead of having a common base view model you could write a custom HTML helper that will retrieve this information from the database and return it. Of course to avoid multiple roundtrips to the database you could cache the retrieved user settings into the `HttpContext.Items`.

Comment: Yeah, never would've gone with the static class but mentioned it to rule it out as possible answer :-) Already thought the base class would've been the best solution but didn't think of the action filter nor the HTML helper. I'll look into both. Thanks!